# How to compare two different Dates?

Tags: python, jinja2

I've created a timestamp that get finished after 10 minutes inside my database, inside my template i also created a **jinja set variable** `{% set now = moment().format('DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm:ss') %}`

The timestamp date is : **23-05-2017 19:50:00**

My current date is : **23-5-2017 19:42:22**

If i want to compare timestamp with the current date , i get true every time even that the current date is less than the timestamp .

Here is the code :

```
{% set now = moment().format('DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm:ss') %}
<h4>{{moment().format('DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm')}}</h4>
<h4>{{appo.timestamp.strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')}}</h4>

{% if now < appo.timestamp.strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S') %}

  <h5>The appointment not finished yet.</h5>

{% elif now > appo.timestamp.strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')  %}

  <h5>The appointment already finished.</h5>

{% endif %}
```

Am always getting **The appointment get finished.**

Please, any suggestions !!!

Comment: Why not compare the *timestamp* directly?

Comment: Why are you doing all those conversions to strings? Why not compare the actual datetime objects?

Comment: I want to compare the timestamp with the current time, so if the time passed the appointment should be finished !!

Comment: @zhenguoli , why i should to compare the timestamp directly !

Comment: You should compare the timestamps directly because it's the right thing to do. You have two timestamps: you compare two timestamps without making them in to strings first. If you want to compare two fruits, you just compare them, you don't make them into juice first.

Comment: @PalleDue, right. +1. And the timestamp is integer, comparing it will be more efficient.

Comment: I think its the same if i compared the current time with timestamp or vice versa it must be the same i think !!

Comment: No, it's not. If you do a compare of timestamp 10-05-2017 and 01-06-2017 the latter will be bigger. If you turn them into strings you will do a lexicographical comparison and the former will be bigger.

Comment: So its like which is bigger -1 or 1 , i understand i will give it a try :) .

Comment: I tried what you guys mentioned above, it doesn't work, even i tried to make a custom `jinja filter` which convert string timestamp to object, it doesn't work, any help please , maybe i don't understand the process very well !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found that a datetime object can create a new datetime object:

```
In [1]: import datetime

In [2]: wasNow = datetime.datetime.now()

In [3]: wasNow
Out[3]: datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 28, 14, 17, 21, 889530)

In [4]: wasNow.now()
Out[4]: datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 28, 14, 17, 30, 105077)
```

and now that you have a date object in the jinja template you are able to create a new datetime object from an existing one and compare it like:

```
{% if item.date < item.date.now() %}
  <p> This will display if the item.date is before item.date.now(). </p>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

I already solved the problem.

I just made a custom template filter that checks if the status of the appointment is finished or not.

Here is the code:

```
@app_route.app_template_filter('getstatus')
def getstatus(id):
    appointment = Appointment.query.filter_by(id=int(id)).first_or_404()
    date = datetime.now()
    if date > appointment.end_time:
        return True
    elif date < appointment.end_time:
        return False
environment.filters['getstatus'] = getstatus
```

Above as you can see i am comparing object with object, so if the current date **datetime.now** is greater than **appointment.end_time** return **true** which means the appointment is finished else not finished .